# Dynamic pie chart creation in .net

Tags: asp.net

I want to create a pie chart in my asp.net web site.The chart should get the values from database and generate a pie chart as well.
Please help me ,how do i get this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I would say have a look at the Asp.Net Charting control. [New ASP.NET Charting Control - ScottGu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx) . The samples found in that post are quite detailed and cover numerous chart types.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of charting components you can use in ASP.NET, including free ones.

For server-side rendering I can recommend **[ASP.NET Charting](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx)** from Microsoft (formerly Dundas Charts)
For client-side rendering you can use **[HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com)** or **[AmCharts](http://www.amcharts.com)** (requires flash).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Fusion Charts. Ive implemented it in my project. Its easier to implement and is also very professional.

There is also a helper for Fusion Charts with Asp.Net (webforms and mvc)

Here a sample for a Pie Chart:

http://liberofusioncharts.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Single%20Series%20Chart,%20adding%20data%20by%20DataSource&referringTitle=Home

Project site: http://liberofusioncharts.codeplex.com/